# I dont know why PAGE cant work with that interface repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-19 21:37:34.254 ERROR 11296 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cinemaProjetApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cinemaInitService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cinemaInitServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filmRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filmRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.sid.dao.FilmRepository.findByNameContains(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property name found for type Film!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.sid.CinemaProjetApplication.main(CinemaProjetApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cinemaInitServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filmRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filmRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.sid.dao.FilmRepository.findByNameContains(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property name found for type Film!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filmRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.sid.dao.FilmRepository.findByNameContains(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property name found for type Film!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.sid.dao.FilmRepository.findByNameContains(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property name found for type Film!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type Film!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted

enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYYxW.png)

Comment: Please add your source code as text and not as image. Please format your code and error.

Comment: Did you read the exception? It kind of explains why it fails

Comment: yes u r right kinda new to Spring Boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.sid.dao.FilmRepository.findByNameContains(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property name found for type Film!
```

It says clearly that entity `Film` has no `name` property.

Comment: I missed up with the Class film thought a similar attribute which is Name and it was called Tiltle Ty